# Problems with jQuery dialog, linking certain id's

Tags: jquery, href

Currently next to no JavaScript experience so using a code from jQuery's site which is as follows;

```
$(function(){
    $("a").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<div/>', {'class':'myDlgClass', 'id':'link-'+($(this).index()+1)})
        .html($('<iframe/>', {
            'src' : $(this).attr('href'),
            'style' :'width:100%; height:100%;border:none;'
        })).appendTo('body')
        .dialog({
            'title' : $(this).text(),
            'width' : 1150,
            'height' :450,
            'resizable' :false,
        }); 
    });
});
```

It works when I click any "href", however I'm only wanting it too work on some href's not everyone on the site.  So hoping there is a way I can change the JavaScript so I can set a href id to only work on them.

Comment: You should read about `Query Selectors` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector. `$("a") is the selector for anchor tags. You need to target the element(s) that you want through a CSS class or ID properties or other element attributes.

Comment: Also, please understand that this code is `JavaScript` which is different from `Java.`

Answer (score 0):

firts params in Jquery should be ID in DOM

```
$('<div/>', {'class':'myDlgClass', 'id':'link-'+($(this).index()+1)})
```

should be

```
$('#your_id', {'class':'myDlgClass', 'id':'link-'+($(this).index()+1)})
```

Comment: if I change the code too
`
$('#your_id', {'class':'myDlgClass', 'id':'link-'+($(this).index()+1)}
)`

and add <a id="your_id" href="#">apple</a>

Then that link doesn't work nor do any link on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class to each anchor tag which you want to trigger the event listener. Here you go:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="your-class">Link that trigger event listener</a>
<a href="https://google.com">Link that does not trigger event listener</a>
<a href="#" class="your-class">Link that trigger event listener</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $(".your-class").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // your rest of the code...
    });
});
```

Running example:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".your-class").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        alert("Triggered!");
    });
});
```

```css
a{ display: block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="your-class">Link that triggers event listener</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Link that does not trigger event listener</a>
<a href="#" class="your-class">Another link that triggers event listener</a>
```

You can also call methods on html's `onclick` attribute if its not a hassle for you.

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="foo();">Link 1</a>
<a href="https://google.com">Link 2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="foo();">Link 3</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function foo(){
    // your code here...
    alert("You clicked me!");
}
```